# Are there any generally accepted standards for larp weapons?

Tags: weapons, larp, props

Many historical and fantasy larps use latex covered foam weapons for combat simulation and some of these larps (presumably) have minimum standards for these weapons.

[image]

I know that many games have minimum standards for weapons construction.

What would be the most popular or widely used construction standards used?

Comment: In its current form, this question is likely too broad for RPG.SE. Please elaborate on the specific constraints and goals your group has for weapons, which can help us to provide better answers.

Comment: Hi Grubermensch, I'm trying to find the most popular accepted weapons standard for larp weapons (if one exists). That doesn't seem too broad for a question.

Comment: I think this is a fair question, as long as you are fine with the answer of "there's not one single set of standards, there's a bunch of them which vary by LARP organization, country, etc." If you're looking for a list of standards, that'd be off-topic. Your comments on other answers seem to indicate you  have further requirements as to what would make a good answer that you don't state in the question; I think clarifying those would help people not see this as a list question.

Comment: What I'm mostly looking for is a popular minimum standard. That may be simple (anything covered in three inches of foam) or it may be very precise (maximum diameter of core =  10mm, minimum thickness of foam on striking surface = 20mm, etc). I don't mind.

Comment: Every LARP group has some kind of standard, so this is an unlimited-list question.

Comment: @mxyzplk I've played in a lot of larps but none of them have *ever* had a written minimum requirement for weapons. Mostly people just bang them on their forearm and decided if they hit too hard.

Comment: It's interesting to see that of the five people who have put this question on hold none of them have posted a question with a larp tag... Guys; do you even larp?

Comment: @DerekTomes They may not, but a lack of experience with the subject matter does not always preclude one from accurately identifying a question as problematic. (Then again, sometimes it does.)

Answer (score 1):

After all I have read and seen, it seems that the standards for LARP weapons are depending on the country/area where the LARP takes place.

The **technical standards** in Germany (at least, probably more countries in Europe), if selfmade, is pretty much:
a bar of fiberglass as center, to stabilize the weapon, then some layers of mats made of foam material. the fiberglass bar has to be shorter than the weapon itself, and (I think it's best practice) to make it even more safe, you put/glue some leather around the tips (of the bar, so you won't see it on the outside). After that just glueing the layer of mats of foam material, and when it's dry, coloring it and complete it with a layer of latex or topcoat.
In short: fiberglass bar as core, ends of the bar secured with leather, and some layers of foam material mats around it. Safety always comes first! (Though it still is also important that it also looks good/normal.

The **styling standards** are... well... depending on the group and the kind of LARP you are playing. A little bit of personal preference, but also thinking of a little bit realism. (i.e. don't make the weapons way too large. This looks nice in some Final Fantasy games, but pretty much ridiculous if the character holding it isn't some kind of very, veeery mighty and strong... thing.)

Comment: That's how I've been making weapons for year, but I was wondering if groups had any minimum foam thickness requirements, etc.

Comment: This is pretty much depending on the geographical region, as I've mentioned before.
In general, just stay with the rule: as long, as you can't feel the core bar when you're hit with it, it is okay. With "not feeling it", I mean that a layer being 1 mm thick won't effectively cushion the core. I don't remember the general thickness of those foam layers, but if you build the weapon and think it is still too hard, you can still add a thinner layer of foam. There won't be a general "minimum standard" except group intern (or regional) standards that could accurately answer your question.

Answer (score -2):

A quick look at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foam_weapon) shows a couple of different types of boffer weapons. Standards are apparently set on a per group basis, determined by degree of contact. A [Google search for boffer standards](https://www.google.com/search?q=boffer%20standards&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US) returns a bunch of how-to's from various game groups and the SCA.

Comment: Thanks '7809, the wikipedia article you reference doesn't really contain what I would consider 'construction standards' it's more an overview of larp weapons. 

Thank you for your suggestion on using google to search the internet but if that had given me a comprehensive answer I wouldn't be asking here. 

You obviously also googled and didn't manage to find a comprehensive answer either.